# Skipping my code, how i can fix this?

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;

public class studLink {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Student> stud = new LinkedList<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome To Student Data Manager");
        while (true) {
            try {
                int a;
                do {
                    System.out.println("1. Add first\n2. Add between\n3. Add last");
                    a = scan.nextInt();
       if (a == 1) {
                        System.out.print("Student name : ");
                        String name = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student matric : ");
                        String matric = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student CGPA : ");
                        double cgpa = scan.nextDouble();
                        stud.addFirst(new Student(name, matric, cgpa));

                        try {
                            int c;
                            do {
                                System.out.println("1. Add more\n2. Delete one\n3. Print dean list");
                                c = scan.nextInt();
                                if (c == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Add More");
                                } else if (c == 2) {
                                    try {
                                        int e;
                                        do {
                                            System.out.println("1. Delete first\n2. Delete Between\n3. Delete last");
                                            e = scan.nextInt();
                                            if (e == 1) {
                                                stud.removeFirst();
                                            } else if (e == 2) {
                                                System.out.print("Position to remove : ");
                                                int f = scan.nextInt();
                                                stud.remove(f);
                                            } else if (e == 3) {
                                                stud.removeLast();
                                            } else {
                                                System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                            }
                                        } while (e != 1 && e != 2 && e != 3);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }

                                } else if (c == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Dean List");
                                    for (Student st : stud) {
                                        int i = 1;
                                        i++;
                                        if (st.getCgpa() >= 3.75) {
                                            System.out.println("-------Student " + i + " -------");
                                            System.out.println("Name = " + st.getName());
                                            System.out.println("Matric No = " + st.getMatric());
                                            System.out.println("CGPA = " + st.getCgpa());
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                }

                            } while (c != 1 && c != 2 && c != 3);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
     else if (a == 2) {
                        System.out.print("Enter position : ");
                        int pos = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("Student name : ");
                        String name = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student matric : ");
                        String matric = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student CGPA : ");
                        double cgpa = scan.nextDouble();
                        stud.add(pos, new Student(name, matric, cgpa));
                        try {
                            int c;
                            do {
                                System.out.println("1. Add more\n2. Delete one\n3. Print dean list");
                                c = scan.nextInt();
                                if (c == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Add More");
                                } else if (c == 2) {
                                    try {
                                        int e;
                                        do {
                                            System.out.println("1. Delete first\n2. Delete Between\n3. Delete last");
                                            e = scan.nextInt();
                                            if (e == 1) {
                                                stud.removeFirst();
                                            } else if (e == 2) {
                                                System.out.print("Position to remove : ");
                                                int f = scan.nextInt();
                                                stud.remove(f);
                                            } else if (e == 3) {
                                                stud.removeLast();
                                            } else {
                                                System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                            }
                                        } while (e != 1 && e != 2 && e != 3);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }

                                } else if (c == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Dean List");
                                    for (Student st : stud) {
                                        int i = 1;
                                        i++;
                                        if (st.getCgpa() >= 3.75) {
                                            System.out.println("-------Student " + i + " -------");
                                            System.out.println("Name = " + st.getName());
                                            System.out.println("Matric No = " + st.getMatric());
                                            System.out.println("CGPA = " + st.getCgpa());
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                }

                            } while (c != 1 && c != 2 && c != 3);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    } 
     else if (a == 3) {
                        System.out.print("Student name : ");
                        String name = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student matric : ");
                        String matric = scan.next();
                        System.out.print("Student CGPA : ");
                        double cgpa = scan.nextDouble();
                        stud.addLast(new Student(name, matric, cgpa));
                        try {
                            int c;
                            do {
                                System.out.println("1. Add more\n2. Delete one\n3. Print dean list");
                                c = scan.nextInt();
                                if (c == 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Add More");
                                } else if (c == 2) {
                                    try {
                                        int e;
                                        do {
                                            System.out.println("1. Delete first\n2. Delete Between\n3. Delete last");
                                            e = scan.nextInt();
                                            if (e == 1) {
                                                stud.removeFirst();
                                            } else if (e == 2) {
                                                System.out.print("Position to remove : ");
                                                int f = scan.nextInt();
                                                stud.remove(f);
                                            } else if (e == 3) {
                                                stud.removeLast();
                                            } else {
                                                System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                            }
                                        } while (e != 1 && e != 2 && e != 3);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }

                                } else if (c == 3) {
                                    System.out.println("Dean List");
                                    for (Student st : stud) {
                                        int i = 1;
                                        i++;
                                        if (st.getCgpa() >= 3.75) {
                                            System.out.println("-------Student " + i + " -------");
                                            System.out.println("Name = " + st.getName());
                                            System.out.println("Matric No = " + st.getMatric());
                                            System.out.println("CGPA = " + st.getCgpa());
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                                }

                            } while (c != 1 && c != 2 && c != 3);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter available number");
                    }
                } while (a != 1 && a != 2 && a != 3);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is if i chose number 1 and 3, next code is fine. but if i enter 2, its skipping the rest of code. i made this code looping back to the first while progress finish.

this is the example problem output

```
Welcome To Student Data Manager
1. Add first
2. Add between
3. Add last
2 //this is input number
Enter position : 2
Student name : wqefq
Student matric : 434
Student CGPA : 2
1. Add first
2. Add between
3. Add last
```

what i need is like this when i enter 2

```
Welcome To Student Data Manager
1. Add first
2. Add between
3. Add last
1 //this is input number
Student name : hoiaufh
Student matric : 2344
Student CGPA : 4
1. Add more
2. Delete one
3. Print dean list
```

the main option is

```
if(a==1)
else if(a==2)
else if(a==3)
```

in the main code above

Comment: Step 1: properly indent your code. Step 2: split your code into methods.

Comment: Your code is not readable to me, and I doubt you are able to read it. Please use proper indentation and extract some methods with proper names.

Comment: Post a [mcve] showing the condition and input. the code inside the condition are useless unless they update the input value. For the rest, read the comments above

Comment: One more piece of advice: your `if/else` could be turned into a slightly more convenient `switch/case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the pos value of the line

```
stud.add(pos, new Student(name, matric, cgpa));
```

Are you sure that pos is a valid index? From [add documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,%20E)):

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

**EDIT**

To handle this is the problem you can do

```
if (stud.size() < pos)
    //error (print error message?)
else {
    // go on with other instructions
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure about it. actually its not full my code. this is group assignment. and how i fix this?

Comment: Especially if this is a team effort, you *really*, **really** should split that code into some well-defined, properly named methods. If I were you, that's what I'd do first. Right now.